# How to create an activity for notifications?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging for my app.I am done with the notifications part but I want to know, how  can we create an activity containing all the notifications received by the user in RecyclerView?

Comment: Did you try storing all received notifications in a SQLite database?

Comment: No i didnt use sqlite

Comment: Should i use sqlite

Comment: You can... I was asking if you had tried, as that's the developer guide documented way for Android data persistence

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase also for database, you can try storing all the notifications the user receives to the users ID in the database. Then you can just retrieve all the database items and display it in a list

Comment: Is there any other way than to store in firebase database.Because i dont want to retrieve data again and again.

Comment: @Shubham Firebase provides the option to cache locally and only return data that's changed on the database. Search for offline mode of firebase documentation